# How can I access the public methods on a module from a private?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, revealing-module-pattern

I have this really annoying problem. I need to able to access the public module function from within a private module pattern. I have written a comment on the problematic line...is there any way to do this?

```
angular.module("myApp").factory('models', [function () {

    function itemModel(dtoItem) {

        this.type = dtoItem.type;

    }

    function groupModel(dto) {

        this.items = [];

        angular.forEach(dto.getFeatures(), function (item) {
            self.items.push(new itemModel(item)); //THIS NEEDS TO BE self.items.push(new ItemModel(item)); (Notice the use of the capital letter to denote a public function) so that I can run a test externally and check the type of the 'items'
        });

    }

    return {
        ItemModel: itemModel,
        GroupModel: groupModel
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the book [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) I have realised you can't.